# DJ: pioneer DDJ-T1 with traktor in ubuntu by wine

Tags: wine

I have a friend who wants to move to Ubuntu. She is a DJ and she would like to use her pioneer DDJ-T1 with `traktor` by wine.

She has run `traktor` without problem. But the problem is that `traktor` or Ubuntu doesn't detect the Pioneer.

Anyone knows about that ?

Comment: Under Ubuntu you may wish to give a chance to Mixxx (http://www.mixxx.org). Mapping the device can be done but it seems nobody has already a complete mapping for it. So you will have to create the proper assignments for each control on your device. Several knobs and sliders may work as right out of the box. If your friend is engaged to Traktor she will love Mixxx. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I will encourage het to try Mixxx. If not I have been thinking about virtualbox... but we would prefer not to use windows as part of the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Wine doesn't support driver installation.
So I suppose what your asking is just not possible.
*Edit 1:* But it seems to be possible using that workaround, but as I do not have your hardware I can't tell you more thant this :
http://wiki.winehq.org/USB